# Персидский язык на сайте

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, локализация

Заказчик попросил добавить на сайт поддержку Персидского языка. Интересует все, что может пригодится по типу кодировок сайта и БД, что учитывать при заполнении форм с текстом и добавлении его в БД.

Comment: Счастье, есть будет: unicode, utf-8

Comment: То-есть utf-8 достаточно? Там вроде же текст читается с права на лево не?

Comment: ну да. rtl в первую очередь. Как бы не пришлось "зеркалить" весь шаблон при смене языка

Comment: Чтобы просто вывести текст, utf-8 вполне достаточно. Только вот скорее всего весь интерфейс сайта необходимо отзеркалить, а это уже весьма сложная задача https://habr.com/company/2gis/blog/416635/

Comment: Хотя тонкости вывода текста тоже существуют: https://habr.com/company/2gis/blog/358148/